# How to show a username seperated from domain name like domain\username: in ASP.net so it can be used as a value

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, domain-name, login-name

I'm setting up an application where in the footer, a Site.Master file contains a text Label to show "Welcome, username". Although I applied the right code, i cannot seem to get out text for the username.

I'm pretty new at this so can't see what I am doing anymore. Thank you so much in advance.

In the Site.Master file:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

In the Site.Master.cs file:

```
WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
if (windowsIdentity == null)
throw new InvalidOperationException("WindowsIdentity is null");
string nameWithoutDomain = windowsIdentity.Name.Split('\\').Last();

Label1.Text = String.Format("Welcome,{0}", nameWithoutDomain);
```

[SOLUTION]

```
 var windowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

            if (windowsIdentity == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("WindowsIdentity is null");
            string nameWithoutDomain = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last();

            Label1.Text = String.Format("Welcome,{0}", nameWithoutDomain);
```

Comment: This looks like it would work... when you run the application what are you getting? 



I've confirmed the below code works as expected:

`string name = "mydomain\\JManuel";
Console.WriteLine(name.Split('\\').Last());
// outputs: JManuel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` gets the identity that the web site is running with, which will usually be the application pool identity. This is not the current user that has logged into your web site (unless you are using impersonation).

Use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` instead, which will give you the identity used to authenticate the current HTTP request.

This assumes that you have Windows Authentication working properly.

Comment: Thank you, could you show me where to place this in the current code I have supplied? Or shoud I just replace WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() with HttpContext.Current.User.Identity ?

Comment: Just replace `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` with `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` :) Easy as that.

Comment: Noted like this: WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity();    It gives me an error "Non-invocable member 'IPrinciple.Identity' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: It's not a method; it's a property. Just remove the `()` at the end.

Comment: I'm so sorry man.. but it still gives me an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Security.Principal.IIdentity'  to ' System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Hrm. That sounds like your Windows Authentication isn't working properly. Technically it will be an [`IIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iidentity) object, which *could* not be `WindowsIdentity`, but it should be if Windows Authentication is working. You can try just using `var windowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;` You are only using the `Name` property, which isn't something specific to `WindowsIdentity`. See what the value of `.Name` is, but it might not be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for this addition @GabrielLuci. Still not working. I tried to dig deeper by just checking out the following:  Under Page_Load in .aspx using: `string var = "blabla"; Label1.Text = var;` and `<asp:TextBox ID="Label1" runat="server" />` on .cs  shows me an empty Textbox on the page. Shouldn't it show blabla in the textbox?

Comment: I can't say. Does it not complain about the use of `var` as a variable name? But in any case, what's the value of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: With `var windowsIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;` `string nameWithoutDomain = windowsIdentity.Name.Split('\\').Last();` `Label1.Text = String.Format("Welcome,{0}", nameWithoutDomain);` in .cs and `<asp:TextBox ID="Label1" runat="server"  />` I get no value/result or text in Label1

Comment: Start debugging in Visual Studio. Set a breakpoint in your code, and when your app stops at that breakpoint, put `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` in the Watch window.

Comment: Thanks. Value in `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` shows   `"DOMAIN\\username"` type `string`

Comment: Fixed it! By using `string nameWithoutDomain = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last();` Thanks a lot @Gabriel Luci !